# Ansible using the first value from an array

Tags: ansible

My latest Ansible playbook is designed to setup new users on our redhat systems. Each environment has their own user list defined like:

```
users:
  - loginid: "someuser"
    name: This_guy
    groups: []
    password: "{{ newuser_pass }}"
    ssh_public_key: []
```

and my issue here is the groups array. While it's an empty array here it might be defined as

```
groups:
  - admins
  - dbas
  - managers
```

I've got a task using the Ansible user module and I want to set the group for the user to the first value in this array. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
group: "{{ item.groups.[0] if item.groups.[0] exists else 'users' }}"
```

You can see here that if no groups are defined the user gets "users" or a catchall group as their default. But how how grab the "admins" as the user's default? obviously, the above line isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
group: "{{ (item.groups | first) if (item.groups | count > 0) else 'users' }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin, I didn't know that first was a valid parameter. Works great.